# paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner

Tags: python-3.x, ssh

I have a script that logs into a device, runs commands and dumps the output to a text file.  Script is working fine finally however I am running into an issue when I try to connect to a remote device like over the VPN.  I have a stable VPN connection and I can successfully log into those devices without any issues from my terminal.  However when I run the script I get errors shown below.  I have tried to follow some threads on the error my not understanding it.  Does it have to do with the timeout ?

> > File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/netmiko/ssh_dispatcher.py",
> >     line 246, in ConnectHandler
> >         return ConnectionClass(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py",
> >     line 317, in **init**
> >         self._open()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py",
> >     line 322, in _open
> >         self.establish_connection()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py",
> >     line 884, in establish_connection
> >         self.remote_conn_pre.connect(**ssh_connect_params)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py",
> >     line 406, in connect
> >         t.start_client(timeout=timeout)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py",
> >     line 660, in start_client
> >         raise e   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py",
> >     line 2039, in run
> >         self._check_banner()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py",
> >     line 2216, in _check_banner
> >         "Error reading SSH protocol banner" + str(e) paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner

And here is my script:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import sys

def sh_ap_sumcdp():

    ipaddr = input('IP:''')
    net_connect =  ConnectHandler(ip = ipaddr,port = 22,username = 'admin',password = 'xxxxxx',device_type = 'cisco_wlc_ssh')
    net_connect.find_prompt()
    '(Cisco Controller) >'
    cmd = 'show ap summary'
    output = net_connect.send_command(cmd)
    sys.stdout = open('wlccon.txt', 'w')
    print(output)
    cmd = 'show ap cdp ne all'
    output = net_connect.send_command(cmd)
    print(output)

sh_ap_sumcdp()
```